# Boolean values and core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, boolean

I have Boolean values in a entity, the values are all show 0. 
The values are fetched and no matter what I always get back a TRUE value. 
Here is the code, the problem is probably at the last 2 lines of code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
-(NSInteger)getStatus:(NSString*)nameID;
{

 **//Fetch Request**

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity =
        [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"status"
                    inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
                                        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                      predicateWithFormat:@"id_Name = %@", nameID];
                      [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext]  executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {

    }

    **//Values**

    status *ENT_status;
    ENT_status = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];

    //Either way, both these lines return YES when it would be NO
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    BOOL one = ENT_status.status_one;
    NSNumber *two   = [NSNumber numberWithBool:ENT_status.status_two];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, boolean values are represented as `NSNumber` objects in the managed objects.
So you can either use it as it is:

```
NSNumber *one = ENT_status.status_one;
```

or convert it to a plain (scalar) `BOOL`:

```
BOOL one = [ENT_status.status_one boolValue];
```

(In your code, the *pointer* `ENT_status.status_one` is always interpreted as `YES`.)

Alternatively, you can use the option "Use scalar properties for primitive data types"
when creating the managed object subclass in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late and probably no one is using Objective-C anymore but i came across this problem and what worked for me was:

to retrieve a boolean value from object:

```
BOOL myBool = [[myManagedObject valueForKey:@"myKey"] boolValue];
```

and to set the new value:

```
myManagedObject.myKey = @YES;
```